# How to get table record count by passing table name as parameter using LINQ TO SQL

Tags: vb.net, linq, linq-to-sql

I have a method called getTableRecordCount.

```
 Public Function getTableRecordCount(ByVal strTableName As String, ByVal iParam1 As Integer, iParam2 As Integer) As Boolean


        Try
            Dim detailReturned = (From paramTableName In dc.<need to pass the strTableName here>
                                  Where paramTableName.col1 = iParam1 And paramTableName.col2 = iParam2 
                                  Select paramTableName).Count

            If (detailReturned > 0) Then
                Return True
            Else
                Return False
            End If

        Catch ex As Exception
            .....
        End Try

  End Function
```

If I can pass the table name and have the DataContext I can use the same method for getting other tables
record count. Any input on how to achieve this?

Comment: I assume this helps: [LINQ to SQL: Dynamic SQL table name](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/linqprojectgeneral/thread/6273d072-f500-4382-afb4-8eafd185794d/)

Comment: Bit off-topic, but `Any` in stead of `Count` is far more efficient here.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a method where you pass a data context and expression.
Then from data context (based on Linq2Sql as you did not specify framework) you can get table by using

```
GetTable<T>()
```

method on your data context.

Expression would be your parameters.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully my VB is okay; I'm more comfortable in C#. I'm not sure if this would work with LINQ to SQL, but the GetTableRecordCount test near the bottom does pass. I'm assuming you're working with different data types in your tables, hence the generic method.

```
Imports System.Text
Imports System.Linq.Expressions

Class Product
    Public Id As Integer
    Public Name As String
    Sub New(id As Integer, name As String)
        Me.Id = id
        Me.Name = name
    End Sub
End Class

Class Order
    Public Id As Integer
    Public NumberOfItems As Integer
    Sub New(id As Integer, numItems As String)
        Me.Id = id
        Me.NumberOfItems = numItems
    End Sub
End Class

Class DataContext
    Public Property Products As IEnumerable(Of Product)
    Public Property Orders As IEnumerable(Of Order)
    Sub New()
        Me.Products = New Product() {New Product(1, "Apple"), New Product(2, "Banana")}
        Me.Orders = New Order() {New Order(1, 20), New Order(2, 50)}
    End Sub
End Class

<TestClass()>
Public Class Main
    Dim MyDataContext As DataContext

    <TestMethod()>
    Public Sub GetTableRecordCount()
        Me.MyDataContext = New DataContext()
        Assert.IsTrue(Me.GetTableRecordCount(Of Product)("Products", Function(p) p.Id, 1, Function(p) p.Name.Length, 5))
        Assert.IsTrue(Me.GetTableRecordCount(Of Order)("Orders", Function(o) o.Id, 2, Function(o) o.NumberOfItems, 50))
    End Sub

    Private Function GetTableRecordCount(Of TRow)(tableName As String, getParam1 As Func(Of TRow, Integer), iParam1 As Integer, getParam2 As Func(Of TRow, Integer), iParam2 As Integer) As Boolean
        Try
            Dim propertyExpr = Expression.Property(Expression.Constant(Me.MyDataContext), tableName)
            Dim getTableData = Expression.Lambda(Of Func(Of IEnumerable(Of TRow)))(propertyExpr).Compile()

            Dim detailReturned =
             From row In getTableData()
             Where getParam1(row) = iParam1 And getParam2(row) = iParam2
             Select row

            Return detailReturned.Count() > 0

        Catch ex As Exception
            Return False
        End Try

    End Function
End Class
```